# FOR loop in Excel - find and replace

Tags: vba, excel, replace

I have the following code

```
Sub CleanCat()
Dim i As Integer

For i = 1 To 50

    Columns("A").Replace What:="Cat" & i, Replacement:="Category" & i, LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, ReplaceFormat:=False
    Columns("A").Replace What:="Cat " & i, Replacement:="Category" & i, LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, ReplaceFormat:=False
    Columns("A").Replace What:="Category " & i, Replacement:="Category" & i, LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, ReplaceFormat:=False
    Columns("A").Replace What:="Category" & i, Replacement:="Category" & i, LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, ReplaceFormat:=False

    Columns("A").Replace What:="cat" & i, Replacement:="Category" & i, LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, ReplaceFormat:=False
    Columns("A").Replace What:="cat " & i, Replacement:="Category" & i, LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, ReplaceFormat:=False
    Columns("A").Replace What:="category " & i, Replacement:="Category" & i, LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, ReplaceFormat:=False
    Columns("A").Replace What:="category" & i, Replacement:="Category" & i, LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, ReplaceFormat:=False

Next                                                     
End Sub
```

What I want is to loop through every cell in column A and do the replacements shown (I am looping through tweets) but this doesn't replace everything. I get stuff such as `something cat 13 here` left

Example tweets:

```
@thisaccount  I nominate @thataccountfor category 12 #somehashtag
Cat 12 I nominate @thisaccount #somehashtag
```

Any ideas?

Comment: My guess is that the "space" is not a true space but another character that looks like a space.

Comment: `cat 13` is not the same as `cat13` and you should loop backwards so that replacing `cat 1` doesn't replace `cat 13`.

Comment: To add to what @ScottCraner said, try `Columns("A").Replace What:=chr(160), Replacement:=chr(32))` before entering the loop.

Comment: See my edit to deal with my comment under @Jeeped answer.

Answer (score 2):

Another option without the number loop. (Note: I built on @Jeeped's answer)

It also puts the words in an array for easier updating.

```
Sub CleanCat()
    Dim i As Long
    Dim srch() As Variant
    Dim srchPart As Variant

    srch = Array("Category ", "Category", "Cat ", "Cat") ' make sure this is in order longest to shortest.

    With Worksheets("Sheet1")
        .Columns("A") = .Evaluate("INDEX("'" & A:A,)")
        .Columns("A").Replace What:=Chr(160), Replacement:=Chr(32), LookAt:=xlPart

        For Each srchPart In srch
            .Columns("A").Replace What:=srchPart, Replacement:="}}}}", LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, ReplaceFormat:=False
        Next srchPart

        .Columns("A").Replace What:="}}}}", Replacement:="Category", LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, ReplaceFormat:=False
    End With
End Sub
```

I also stole @Jeeped's formula to test:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

This is all you should require.

```
Option Explicit

Sub CleanCat()
    Dim i As Long

    With Worksheets("sheet1")
        .Columns("A").Replace What:=Chr(160), Replacement:=Chr(32), LookAt:=xlPart
        For i = 50 To 1 Step -1

            .Columns("A").Replace What:="Cat" & i, Replacement:="Category" & i, LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, ReplaceFormat:=False
            .Columns("A").Replace What:="Cat " & i, Replacement:="Category" & i, LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, ReplaceFormat:=False
            .Columns("A").Replace What:="Category " & i, Replacement:="Category" & i, LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, ReplaceFormat:=False

        Next i
    End With
End Sub
```

[image]

My sample data was created with,

```
=CHOOSE(RANDBETWEEN(1, 3), "cat", "Cat", "category")&CHOOSE(RANDBETWEEN(1, 3), TEXT(,), CHAR(32), CHAR(160))&RANDBETWEEN(1, 50)
```

Comment: Do you really need the loop, are we not just replacing `"Cat ","Cat", and "Category "` with `"Category"`? Doesn't the number remain the same? Or did I miss something.

Comment: No, `i` is iterated from numbered categories as I see it. But I see what you mean, that might work. (actually, it looks like it does in you response)

Comment: I still get stuff like this remaining: `...category 12 ...` I am looping through tweets which have ampersands, hashes etc. Should this matter?

Comment: Of course it matters. That is why it is important to show sample data together with expected results. See [mcve]. If you have a 'special' problem, how many guesses do you think we will offer before giving up?

Comment: No need for hostility. When I said it was tweets I made the presumption this would be obvious but apologies if it wasn't. Updated accordingly

Comment: It seems to work when there's a hash at the start of the cell/string

Comment: @pee2pee When the string starts with `@` excel is trying to see it as a formula.  when you import you will need to set those as text string.